# javascript calling a function inside a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that has a callback as a second function

I am trying to figure out how to make this code run:

```
function a() {
    console.log('this ran')
    function firstCB() {
        console.log('now this ran')
    }
}
```

I am trying to run this function by simply calling `a()`

However it doesn't look like I'm running `firstCB()` as only `this ran` is being printed.

What do I need to do to modify this code to make it run as expected?

Comment: why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: You are declaring a whole new function instead of calling the one passed in as argument. Show how you call `a()`

Comment: *"assume I am calling this like a()"* ... then what is the argument for?

Comment: ok updated and added how I'm calling it

Comment: @charlieftl I thought that was how I was supposed to call the callback() but I misread the documentation

Comment: Start by explaining what you want to accomplish...in words

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You just need to call the 2nd function firstCB() to make it run:

```
function a(firstCB) {
    console.log('this ran');
    function firstCB() {
        console.log('now this ran');
    }

    firstCB();
}

a();
```

Comment: ahh, ok. I see, thank you. This is what I was missing. I will mark this answer as correct when I can (in 7 minutes)

Comment: Note this approach has nothing to do with callbacks

Comment: @charlietfl right, if I take out `firstCB` inside of a(), then it works as I expected. I was missing that I have to call the function nested inside of `a()`

Comment: right, I misunderstood what callbacks do, this is just calling a function inside a function

Comment: @MorganAllen yes...that is all it is

Comment: I thought that was a "callback" but completely misunderstood. rephrased the initial question.

Comment: Also get rid of the argument...it is undefined and is confusing based on same name as function

Comment: This is not a callback. This is a plain function invocation

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to pass a callback and invoke it (with `()`) but instead you are re-defining it.

Here's a simple example of how you'd achieve what you want:

```js
function a(firstCB) {
  console.log('this ran')
  firstCB(); // <-- invoke the callback that was passed in
}

a(function firstCB() { // <-- pass in a callback to `a`
  console.log('now this ran')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the callback, don't redefine it:

```
function a(firstCB) {
    console.log('this ran')
    firstCB() ;
    console.log('now this ran')
}
```

Comment: Assumes op is actually passing in a function though. May or may not be the case